# SugarCRM Upgrade from 7.5.2.3 to 7.6.0.0

Tags: upgrade, sugarcrm

SugarCRM does not provide any tools to upgrade from 7.5.2.3 to 7.6.0.0, and I tried to trick their default upgrade package and it didn't take.

What can I do to upgrade from 7.5.2.3 to 7.6.0.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Sugar is working on 7.6.1.0 to patch some major security issues. They navigated around not allowing this upgrade.

But 7.5.2.3 can upgrade to 7.6.1.0 around mid to late August 2015.